# In Android How to check the application was force closed last time

Tags: android

Is there a way to get uncaughed exceptions in Android.
When there is an error in my application I want to send log using mail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is some code that can help you.

first create a class

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private Context context;

    public ExceptionHandler(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("is_force_closed", true).commit();
    }

}
```

then initialize this class in the main activity of your app

```
ExceptionHandler exp = new ExceptionHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: This works only the app crashes by uncaught exceptions

Comment: @solilo but app only force close only on uncaught exception :)

Comment: but in android, user can close apps using some other app, if it claims the permission to close other process

Comment: Then it will not generate a exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can record something when the app exit normally, then you can check the saved data to tell whether it's force closed.